# "Transport encryption required" when using transport encryption

Tags: ldap, radius, freeradius

I'm trying to set up a radius server to authenticate against LDAP, but I'm running into a weird issue:

```
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind with radiusd@[domain] to ldaps://localhost:636 failed: Strong(er) authentication required
rlm_ldap (ldap): Server said: BindSimple: Transport encryption required..
```

As you can see by `ldaps://`, it *is* using transport security. What's going on here? How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** I figured I'd try with starttls. Didn't fix anything:

```
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind with radiusd@[domain] to ldap://localhost:389 failed: Strong(er) authentication required
rlm_ldap (ldap): Server said: BindSimple: Transport encryption required..
```

**EDIT 2:** The hell? It even does it when I pipe it through stunnel.

```
rlm_ldap (ldap): Bind with radiusd@[domain] to ldap://localhost:3636 failed: Strong(er) authentication required
rlm_ldap (ldap): Server said: BindSimple: Transport encryption required..
```

Comment: Just a guess but are you using up to date ciphers?  Maybe it's negotiating to a poor version?

Comment: It was using TLS1.2 so it seems to be fine in that sense.

Comment: What does ldapsearch say when you try with similar arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have no idea what the hell happened, but when I increased my LDAP server's log verbosity in order to debug, the problem just disappeared, and when I put it back it remained gone.